# How to handle ntlm and proxy authentication with selenium and nodejs

Tags: node.js, selenium, google-chrome, firefox, webdriver

Did anyone solve this?

The URL I am trying to access through

```
driver.get("http://example.com")
```

challenges with NTLM authentication and could not handle with selenium. I tried the following but does not work

username:password@url

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue with a tool called Autoit. Basically it allows you write a script which would find out the ntlm box based on the hint that you provide. and fill in username and password and click enter.

ntml_chrome.au3

```
HotKeySet("{ESC}", "Terminate")

For $i=1 to 3
    Local $hWnd = WinWait("Chrome","","10")

    If WinExists($hWnd) Then
        Send("REPLACETHISWITHYOURUSERNAME")
        Send("{TAB}")
        Send("REPLACETHISWITHYOURPASSWORD")
        Send("{Enter}")
    EndIf
Next


Func Terminate()
    Exit 0
EndFunc
```

Which you right click on the file and compile it to give you exe. Run that before you run driver.get(url)

With Nodejs -

```
exec("exe path")
driver.get(url)
```

Hope it helps someone.

Cheers